# how to make not null and constraint FK together in row

Tags: sql, database

for example

```
    create table time
(
  time_emp number(3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT time_emp_FK references employee(emp_id)
);
```

there is an error....
how can i write not null and constraint together in a row???

Comment: Tag the dbms used, your syntax is alright. (`time` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, use `"time"`.)

Comment: "there is an error." - really? Would this error have a *message*, telling you (or, if not you, us), what the specific problem is? Maybe you should [edit] your question and give us this information?

Comment: `time` may be a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

The above statement is fine if your database is Oracle. Just ensure that emp_id in employee table contains unique or primary key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

i am using MySql server and when i declare only one column in MySql with foreign key and not null together it gave error but when i am using this with another column its work fine for me my answer:

```
create table table1(id int(20) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id));
create table table2(id int(20) NOT NULL,pid int(20),PRIMARY KEY(id),FORIEGN KEY(pid) references table1(id));
```